# cloud_firestore package: different behaviour, equivalent queries

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am running a Flutter mobile app that queries data points from Firestore. Until very recently, I have been running the following query:

```dart
    return firestore
      .collection('organisations/$organisationId/alerts/$alertId/deviceTrails/$deviceTrailId/markers')
      .where('deviceCreatedUtc', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: timestamp)
      .snapshots().handleError(handleFirestoreError);
```

I found, while running this query, that it would work well and provide a certain number of snapshots, but that it would stop generating snapshots without throwing any errors after a period of a few minutes. Changing the query to the following seemed to resolve this error (snapshots became more reliable):

```dart
    return firestore
      .collection('organisations/$organisationId/alerts/$alertId/deviceTrails/$deviceTrailId/markers')
      .orderBy('deviceCreatedUtc')
      .startAt([timestamp])
      .snapshots().handleError(handleFirestoreError);
```

Other than the ordering (which is not strictly necessary in my case, since I am adding the points to my on-device database instead of using them directly), there does not appear to be much in the way of functional difference between these queries. But the former fails silently, while the latter is more reliable.

Is there any reason why this would happen? And is one of the queries intrinsically more efficient than the other?

Comment: As far as I can tell those two snippets should do exactly the same (outside of ordering as you said). It might be worth filing a bug on the repo here: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire

Comment: @Rob Lyndon Posted an answer, is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Frank van Puffelen, two snippets should do exactly the same (outside of ordering as you said). You can fill a bug on the repo [here](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire) :

For more information you can refer to the  [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#node.js) (listen a document with onsnapshot() method )and [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/lists-of-data)(working with list of data in flutter firebase.)

> ```
> index.js
>
> const query = db.collection('cities').where('state', '==', 'CA');
>
> const observer = query.onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
>   console.log(`Received query snapshot of size ${querySnapshot.size}`);
>   // ...
> }, err => {
>   console.log(`Encountered error: ${err}`);
> });
> ```